# How to send data back to client, after acquiring the oauth's info

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, httprequest, wechat

The logic flow:

1: client oauth authentication

2: browser redirect back to a predefined URL with client' code

3: server handle the code in the `get` method and acquire the client's data

what I want to achieve:

**after acquiring the oauth data, the server send back the data to the client, then the client's browser can handle the data and make some changes accordingly.**

```
app.get('/callback', function (req, res, next) {

          client.getUser(openid, function (err, result) {
             var userInfo = result; //this is client's userInfo
           //now how can I send back the userInfo object back to the client? 
           //If I use res.send() the client's page will be nothing but just the data
           //I cannot use socket.io here
           //I am not sure If I can use ajax here because usually client does not send a request in the first place
           })

   })
```

Is there a way to send back data without changing the client's page? It seems to be a pretty easy solved problem But I have been scratching my head without coming up with nothing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Ajax is not what you want, you can put `userInfo` as a response parameter and render it in page's html code as JavaScript value. When page is opened in browser, parse this JavaScript value and store it to the global variable (`window`).

**Put `userInfo` as a response parameter**:

```
app.get('/callback', function (req, res, next) {
      client.getUser(openid, function (err, result) {
         var userInfo = result; //this is client's userInfo, assume it is JSON.
         res.locals.userInfoString = JSON.stringify(userInfo);
       })
})
```

**Render it in page's html code, and parse it when page is loaded** (assume [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) template is used, but any other template technology will support the same function):

```
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var userInfoString = '{{userInfoString}}';
    window.userInfo = JSON.parse(userInfoString);
  </script>
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

In this way, you can visit `window.userInfo` in your JavaScript code to get the userInfo object.

---

For Ajax solution, you can send an Ajax request once the page is loaded, fetching userInfo data from server. When the userInfo data is retrieved, change related DOM with jQuery or native JavaScript.

**Send Ajax request once page is loaded, fetching data and change DOM:**

```
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jQuery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $.get('/userInfo', function(data) {
        // change DOM with data.
      });
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

**When `/callback` is visited, get `userInfo` and save it in Database, then return page:**

```
app.get('/callback', function (req, res, next) {
  client.getUser(openid, function (err, result) {
     var userInfo = result;
     // save userInfo into Database.
     res.render('callback_page');
   })
});
```

**When `/userInfo` is visited, get the openid and read userInfo data from database:**

```
app.get('/userInfo', function (req, res, next) {
  // get openid from req
  // get userInfo from database by openid
  res.json(userInfo);
});
```

Comment: I keep getting the "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( in JSON at position 1" error. Is '{{userInfoString}}' holding the value of userInfo? Actually I dont want to rule out ajax but I just dont know know how to implement it...

Comment: yes, `{{userInfoString}}` holds the value of userInfo, but you need to confirm whether it is a JSON. Meanwhile, `{{}}` is `nunjucks`'s syntax for response parameter, if you are using different template, the syntax may be different.

Comment: For Ajax solution, you can send an Ajax request once the page is loaded, fetching userInfo data from server. When the userInfo data is retrieved, change related DOM with jQuery or native JavaScript.

Comment: on server side I intentionally to do var userInfo = { "name":"John", "age":30} to make the data JSON but I still get that error. on the client side, if I omit the JSON.parse medthod and just do var userInfoString = '{{userInfoString}}';
console.log(userInfoString) I'd get the string "{{userInfoString}}" instead of the data it holds. I already install nunjucks to make it work. For the Ajax solution,is it possible to give some code sample?

Comment: @WeiZheng If `{{userInfoString}}` is printed, then I think you didn't make nunjucks work successfully. For Ajax solution, I've added some code example. But I think it is unnecessary for this question's scenario.